# JSF - open different dialog after validation faild

Tags: javascript, jsf

I'd like to open a dialog in with Javascript, but it depends on if the validation is failed or not. Here is my defenition of my Button:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msgs['button.cancel']}"
    rendered="#{!myBean.readOnly}"
    oncomplete="if(args.validationFailed){openDialog1}else{openDialog2}"
    action="verworfen" immediate="true"
    styleClass="button">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
```

But my problem is, when I click on the cancel button, the default dialog of the browser is shown instead of my dialog. 
Someone an idea?

Comment: Can you explain how your dialog works?

Comment: @Thum Choon Tat It is a simple yes-no dialog if you want save the changes or not.

Comment: I don't get the oncomplete part: What is 'args' referring to? I think the standard jsf commandButton does not even have an oncomplete attribute (In contrast to the primefaces commandButton). Are you using primefaces and a primefaces dialogue? Then you could use its widget var like oncomplete=PF('widgetVar').show()...

Comment: `h:commandButton` does not have an `oncomplete` callback. What version of JSF are you running?